# Async Task - read database data, got: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' The query processor could not start the necessary thread resources

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous

### I'm creating Async Tasks in a loop, The task has to read data from sql database.
as the source data size gets bigger, I got this error:

- The query processor could not start the necessary thread resources for parallel query execution.

here is my code:

```
For Each objLocDataTable In pLocationData

    If objLocDataTable IsNot Nothing AndAlso objLocDataTable.ISVALID Then

       listLocationELTTasks.Add(TaskEx.Run(
             Async Function() As Task
                    Dim resTable As System.Data.DataTable = Await mDBUtil.QueryAsync(strQry)

                    ....... 'do calculation works based on the query result
             End Function))
    END if
Next


 Public Async Function QueryAsync(ByVal strSqlQuery As String) As Task(Of DataTable)

  Dim returnDataTable As DataTable = Nothing

  Dim nTriedNumber As Integer = 0, nMaxTryNumber = 10
  Dim bStop As Boolean = False

  While (Not bStop)
   Try
    Using dbConnection As New SqlConnection(mStrConn)
     Using dbComm As New SqlCommand(strSqlQuery, dbConnection)

      Await dbConnection.OpenAsync()
      dbComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text

      Dim readerTask As Task(Of SqlDataReader) = Task.Factory.FromAsync(AddressOf dbComm.BeginExecuteReader, AddressOf dbComm.EndExecuteReader, Nothing)

      returnDataTable = Await readerTask.ContinueWith(
       Function(pervTask)
        Dim resultTable As New DataTable()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = Nothing
        Try
         reader = pervTask.Result
         reader.Read()
         resultTable.Load(reader)
         bStop = True
        Catch ex As Exception
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Thread ID [{0}]: nTriedNumber [{1}], QueryAsync error: {2}", Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, nTriedNumber, ex.Message))
        Finally
         If (reader IsNot Nothing) Then
          reader.Close()
         End If
         If (Not dbConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then
          dbConnection.Close()
         End If
        End Try
        Return resultTable
       End Function)
     End Using
    End Using

   Catch ex As Exception
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Not datareader error, nTriedNumber [{0}], QueryAsync error: {1}", nTriedNumber, ex.Message))
   Finally
    'could be shorten as if( returnDataTable Is Nothing or returnDataTable.Rows.Count() = 5) Then
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Thread ID [{0}]: QueryAsync is sleeping for 1 sec", Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End If

    If (nTriedNumber >= nMaxTryNumber) Then
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Thread ID [{0}]: Reach to max try number, failed to retrieve data", Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))
     bStop = True
    End If
   End Try
  End While

  Return returnDataTable
 End Function
```

#### As in function QueryAsync, I tried
- close the db connection as quick as possible.
- even sleep for a while
none of them working

### Note:
- the sql data source is about 50 million records, I can NOT load it into memory at once before the for loop to do in-memory linq query.

I tried to replace the Task with Parrel.foreach, same result.

what's the efficient way to read data from sql database in task.

Comment: Looks like you are spamming the database with a very high number of queries, all of which are themselves parallel. As the message says, you seem to have exhausted resources.

Comment: yes. exactly, what is the way to release DB resource in time, or put on hold the parallel/task works when DB exhausted?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't need async IO. Switch to synchronous database calls, and your life becomes very easy:

```
pLocationData
.AsParallel()
.WithDegreeOfParallelism(8) //choose the number by testing
.ForEach(objLocDataTable => Query(objLocDataTable));
```

(C# syntax). I've renamed `QueryAsync` to `Query` because it should be a good old synchronous method like we have always used it.

This executes your queries with 8 threads concurrently. A fixed amount of threads will not overload the DB.

Comment: tried, NOT working, exactly same error. and after exactly number of data, stop, and not able to get data anymore.

Comment: But, you're right, no need to use async and task, AsParallel() does the same thing at the same speed before crush

Comment: Set the degree of parallelism to one. If the crash is still occurring, there's probably some other problem. Please post the current code (without async).

Comment: my DBA set degree of parallelism to one and solved this issue.

Comment: Well... he has just disabled parallelism for all queries. This will cost you a lot of performance. This is not a good solution. You should just fix your code. Put higher standards to yourself.

Comment: as SQL DOP set to 1, I don't see this resource exhausted anymore. but without setting DOP, I do get this out of resource error quick offen, as example, in one case, the pLocationData list is about 8500, and each will need to query db for about 500 row of data, and each db row returned has 35 field, most of them are double

Comment: As I take your suggestion, completed removed the async functions and calls, now my code is pretty straightforward, pLocationData.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(8).ForAll(), and insider function call the DB query synchronously, nothing fancy